# request through ajax render to a page not working django

Tags: python, ajax, django

After making an ajax request data is being sent successfully to view. But the render function is not working. Render function should render to dashboard.html with data. I have imported all files needed to render. Is it because of an ajax request. Thanks in advance...

---

**My ajax request from template**

```
$("#campaign").click(function () {
    alert("hey main")
    alert($("#campaign").val());
    var id = $("#campaign").val()
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{% url 'appdata' %}",
        data: {
            userid: id
        }
    }).done(function () {
        alert("Data Sent: ");
    }).fail(function () {
        alert("error");
    });
    /* location.reload()*/
});
```

---

**My urls.py**

```
url(r'^publisher/appdata/?$', 'appdata', name='appdata'),
```

---

**My views.py**

```
def appdata(request):

    print 'hi i am appdata, fetch me after select id'

    print request
    userid = request.POST['userid']
    # print 'userid: %s'%userid
    impressions = Impressions.objects.get(id=userid)
    # print 'impressionid: %s'%impressions.id
    clicks = Clicks.objects.get(id=userid)
    revenues = Revenue.objects.get(id=userid)
    ecpm = App.objects.get(id=userid)
    member = Member.objects.get(id=userid)
    campaigns_id = Campaign.objects.get(id=userid)

    # print campaigns_id
    # print type(campaigns_id)
    apps = App.objects.all()
    # print apps

    # for i in apps:
        # print i.name
    # print len(camps)

    # dict = {'i':impressions, 'c':clicks, 'r':revenues, 'e':ecpm, 'apps': apps, 'member':member, 'c_id':campaigns_id } 
    # print dict['i'].impressions

    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'i':impressions, 'c':clicks, 'r':revenues, 'e':ecpm, 'apps': apps, 'member':member, 'c_id':campaigns_id })
```

Comment: could you see that `'hi i am appdata, fetch me after select id'` in your console?

Comment: yes i can see that in terminal...using ubuntu

Comment: You're returning an HTML page to an Ajax request - is that what you want?  Your handler for the Ajax response does nothing with the response so your web page won't update.

Comment: is there any easy way to update my page "dashboard", using ajax. how can i do that with the response @SteveAllison

Comment: The usual reason to use Ajax is so that you can update a web page without loading a whole new html page.  Typically you would have a service return json data, you then write a jquery handler for the response that uses the data to update the web page -- check out the jQuery documentation for more on this - it's not a simple one liner.

Comment: Is there any way render can work with jquery...?@SteveAllison

Comment: @user2622350 did u found the solution ?

Comment: render can not work with ajax request. It has to return json data